# C# generic type inference versus covariance - bug or restriction

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference, covariance

When a generic method with dependent parameters infers the type it gives unexpected results in some cases. If I specify the type explicitly everything works without any further Changes.

```
IEnumerable<List<string>> someStringGroups = null; // just for demonstration
IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<string>> someSequenceComparer = null;

var grouped = someStringGroups
  .GroupBy(x => x, someSequenceComparer);
```

Of course, above code is not intended to be ever executed, but it demonstrates that the result type of `grouped` is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>,List<string>>` rather than `IEnumerable<List<string>,List<string>>` as expected because of `x => x`.

If I specify the types explicitly everything is fine.

```
var grouped = someStringGroups
  .GroupBy<List<string>,List<string>>(x => x, someSequenceComparer);
```

If I do not use an explicit comparer everything works as expeceted too.

I think that the problem is that taking the least common denominator of the supplied argument types (`IEnumerable<string>`) takes *precedence* over the covariance of the `IEqualityComparer<>` interface. I would have expected the opposite, i.e. a generic method should infer the most specific type that is satisfied by the arguments.

The question is: is this a **bug or a documented behavior?**

Comment: I think you are missing out an IGrouping there. ie `grouped` is of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<IEnumerable<String>,List<String>>>`

Comment: This executes without error for me...

Comment: @MoonKnight: That is correct. The OP is confused about the resulting type and why it is what it is. Though I am surprised it executed without error. I'd have expected an argument exception for doing a `GroupBy` on a null.

Comment: @MoonKnight question is about type inference, executes code or not is irrelevant (question even states "code is not intended to be ever executed").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would have expected the opposite, i.e. a generic method should infer the most specific type that is satisfied by the arguments.

Based on, what, exactly?

The behavior you see is documented and compliant with the C# specification. As you might imagine, the type inference specification is fairly complex. I won't quote the whole thing here, but you can review it yourself if you are interested. The relevant section is **7.5.2 Type inference**.

Based on comments you've written, I think at least part of the confusion stems from you forgetting that there are *three* parameters to this method, not two (which affects how inference proceeds). In addition, it seems you are expecting the second parameter, the `keySelector` delegate, to affect type inference, when it does not in this case (at least, not directly…it creates a dependency between the type parameters, but not in a material way).

But I think the main thing is that you are expecting type inference to be more aggressive about type variance than the specification in fact requires.

During type inference, the first thing that happens is described in the specification, under **7.5.2.1 The first phase**. The second argument is, for all intents and purposes in this phase, ignored. It does not have explicitly declared types for its parameters (though, it wouldn't matter if it did). During this phase, type inference starts to develop *bounds* for the type parameters, but does not fix the parameters themselves.

You are calling this overload of `GroupBy()`:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
```

There are two type parameters that need to be inferred, `TSource` and `TKey`. During inference, it is true that the compiler determines upper- and lower-bounds for the type parameters. But these are based on the types passed to the method call. The compiler does not search for alternate base or derived types that would satisfy the type requirements.

So, for `TSource`, a lower-bound of `List<string>` is identified, while for `TKey`, an upper-bound of `IEnumerable<string>` is identified (**7.5.2.9 Lower-bound inferences**). These types are what you provided to the call, so that's what the compiler uses.

In the second phase, an attempt to fix the types is made. `TSource` does not depend on any other parameter, so it's fixed first, as `List<string>`. A second go-around in the second phase fixes `TKey`. While type variance *allows* the bounds set for `TKey` to accommodate `List<string>`, there's no need, because according to its bounds the type you passed in can be used directly.

Thus, you wind up with `IEnumerable<string>` instead.

Of course, it would have been legitimate (if not compliant with the specification) for the compiler to use `List<string>` as `TKey` instead. We can see this work if the parameter is explicitly cast accordingly:

```
var grouped2 = someStringGroups
  .GroupBy(x => x, (IEqualityComparer<List<string>>)someSequenceComparer);
```

This changes the type of the expression used for the call, thus the bounds used, and finally of course the actual type chosen during inference. But in the original call, the compiler had no need during inference to use a type different from what you specified, even though it would have been allowed, and so it didn't.

The C# specification has some fairly hairy parts to it. Type inference is definitely one of them, and frankly I am not an expert on interpreting this section of the specification. It makes my head hurt, and there are definitely some more challenging corner cases that I probably don't understand (i.e. I doubt I could *implement* this part of the specification, without a lot more study). But I believe the above is a correct interpretation of the parts relevant to your question, and I hope that I've done a reasonable job explaining it.

Comment: Good answer +1. I totally agree with you about the complexity of the Type inference stuff in the spec. Thanks for adding in the more precise details that my answer was lacking. It is what I thought was happening but I wasn't confident enough of exactly which stage it was setting the types to actually state it as fact in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd be pretty sure this is expected behaviour.

The method signature we are interested in is:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer
)
```

`source` is of type `IEnumerable<List<string>>` so the natural choice for `TSource` is `List<string>`. The `comparer` is of type `IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<string>>` so the natural choice for `TKey` is `IEnumerable<string>`.

If we then look at the last parameter `keySelector` is `x=>x`. Does this satisfy the type constraints we have so far? Yes it does because x is a `List<string>`and that can be implicitly converted to an `IEnumerable<string>`.

At this point why should the compiler go looking for anything more? The natural and obvious choices with no casting needed works so it uses that. If you don't like it you always have the option to do as you did and explicitly state the generic parameters.

Or of course you could make your comparer of type `IEqualityComparer<List<string>>` in which case your output object will be of the type you expect (and I hope you can see why this is).

Comment: I can't get why taking the key type from the second argument `IEqualityComarer<IEnumerable<string>>` is more natural than taking it from the first argument `Func<List<string>,List<string>>`. This key type `List<String>` also satisfies the constraints for the comparer argument.

Comment: The exact details of this are in the C# 5 spec (the one I happen to have on my computer) in `7.5.2 Type Inference`. Its quite hard reading and if you want to know exactly what the compiler is doing then you'll want to go and read that and follow through with pen and paper. My interpretation of what it does is the above though but I will agree that my description is not a rigorous one to one mapping with the steps outlined in the specification.

Comment: Online draft of c#6 spec equivalent: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#type-inference

Comment: Also just under https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#inferred-return-type there is an example of type inference with the `Enumerable.Select` method. This backs up my claim that it will match the non-anonymous function parameter first and I assume that extends to both non-anonymous function parameters in this case.

Comment: @Marcel: _"I can't get why taking the key type from the second argument `IEqualityComarer<IEnumerable<string>>` is more natural than taking it from the first argument `Func<List<string>,List<string>>`"_ -- two things are going on there: first, the `keySelector` argument (actually the second, not the first) has no declared types and so couldn't provide types anyway. They'd have to be inferred after other types are determined. ...

Comment: ... Second, even if you had provided types, that parameter's types would only affect the bounds of the types inferred elsewhere; by the time inference has progressed far enough that the compiler would fall back on using the lambda type, it already has enough information from the third argument `comparer`, and all it has left to do is make sure that the inferred type there is compatible with the types required by the `keySelector` argument.