# Generic type parameter to match anything that is IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I have the following C# code that does not behave as I would like.

The requirement is that anything that implements any `IEnumerable<T>` uses the second method that prints `"2"`, but anything else uses the first method that prints `"1"`.

A naive demonstration is below. `ICollection<int>`, `IList<int>`, `List<int>` and `int[]` all implement `IEnumerable<T>` but `"1"` is printed instead of `"2"`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var parent = new Parent<Class>();

            // OK: TProperty == int. Prints "1"
            parent.Map(c => c.IntValue);

            // OK: TProperty == int. Prints "2"
            parent.Map(c => c.IEnumerableIntValue);

            // Wrong: TProperty == ICollection<int>. Prints "1"
            parent.Map(c => c.ICollectionIntValue);

            // Wrong: TProperty == List<int>. Prints "1"
            parent.Map(c => c.ListIntValue);

            // Wrong: TProperty == int[]. Prints "1"
            parent.Map(c => c.ArrayIntValue);
        }

        public class Class
        {
            public int IntValue { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<int> IEnumerableIntValue { get; set; }
            public ICollection<int> ICollectionIntValue { get; set; }
            public List<int> ListIntValue { get; set; }
            public int[] ArrayIntValue { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public class Parent<T>
    {
        public void Map<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
        }

        public void Map<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> expression)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the definition to

```
public void Map<TEnumerable, TElement>(Expression<Func<T, TEnumerable>> expression) where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<TElement>
{
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

but this requires explicit type parameters to use, which is unacceptable:

```
parent.Map<int[], int>(c => c.ArrayIntValue);
```

Has anyone got an ideas on how to achieve this in C# at compile time? Any ideas are appreciated. Maybe contra/covariant delegates could work? I've tried wrangling with the C# compiler but have got nowhere.

Comment: Btw: string implements IEnumerable<char>. Using your expectations, all calls should print "2".

Comment: Now that's an interesting one that I haven't thought of @rind

Comment: How about creating separate method for IEnumerable: `public void MapEnumerable<TElement>(Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TElement>>> expression)`

Comment: ... or specifying the single type parameter to help the compiler pick the desired overload: `Map<string>` disambiguates the calls nicely (except for the very first one which needs to be `Map<char>`).

Comment: @PablonotPicasso I thought about it. But then I need to handle the case of if `IEnumerable<T>` is passed to `Map`. Also I'm developing a 3rd party API and want to make it simple to use. The same applies to the comment about disambiguating. I don't want every called to have to do this.

Comment: Alright, how would you propose dealing with types which implement more than one closed `IEnumerable<>` variant? This is, granted, an unusual scenario, but totally legal in .NET. If you have a strong opinion about how types which implement `IEnumerable<T>` should be handled, perhaps you should be pulling apart the expression argument inside your first `Map` overload and looking at whether its `ParameterExpression.Type`'s interface list contains `IEnumerable<T>` - then handling that case as it suits.

Comment: Related to (possibly duplicate of) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777233/c-sharp-generic-type-inference-versus-covariance-bug-or-restriction/44791195#44791195. Basically, you are asking the compiler to put more effort into overload resolution than the specification calls for. The other question is about inferring the method's type parameter, so I don't think it's exactly the same, but it is fundamentally the same root issue. Overload resolution doesn't do an unbounded search on types nested within other types.

Comment: And no, if you want the compiler to do this for you, the only way to get it to work will be to cast to your expected type explicitly, so that it matches exactly and the method of preference wins. Alternatively, use different method names, instead of making them all overloads of the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UPDATE* My previous answer was downright wrong, didn't think it through properly.

No, you can't do it this way. The reason is that `T` will always be a better match than `IEnumerable<T>` for anything that isn't statically typed as an `IEnumerable<T>`, that's simply how generics work; there can't be a better generic match than `T` unless you have a contending *exact* match.

Consider the following:

```
void Foo<T>(T t) { }
void Foo<T>(IEquatable<T> equatable) { }
```

Would you actually expect `Foo(1)` to resolve to the second overload?

Or have `Foo("hello")` resolve to `Foo<char>(IEnumerable<char>)` when the applicable candidates are:

```
void Foo<T>(T t) { }
void Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) { }
```

The simplest solution is to make an explicit cast when mapping:

```
parent.Map(c => c.ICollectionIntValue.AsEnumerable());
parent.Map(c => c.ListIntValue.AsEnumerable());
//etc.
```

You *could* do something fancy mixing up some reflection with `dynamic` along the following lines:

```
public void Map<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var genericInterfaces = typeof(TProperty).GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.IsGenericType);
    var iEnumerables = genericInterfaces.Where(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(IEnumerable<>))).ToList();

    if (iEnumerables.Count > 1)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Ambiguous IEnumerable<>");

    var iEnumerable = iEnumerables.FirstOrDefault();

    if (iEnumerable == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }
    else
    {
        //ok, we know we have an IEnumerable of something. Let the runtime figure it out.
        Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<dynamic>>> newExpression = e => expression.Compile()(e) as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
        Map(newExpression);
    }
}

public void Map<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> expression)
{
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it really that surprising that the only method whose type argument is unambiguously determined by the compiler to be `IEnumerable<T>` is one that actually deals with `IEnumerable<T>` explicitly?

Here's an unoptimised implementation which dynamically works out whether type `TProperty` unambiguously implements one (and only one) closed version of the `IEnumerable<>` interface, allowing you to process the expression tree differently in that particular case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var parent = new Parent<Class>();

            // OK: TProperty == int. Prints "1"
            parent.Map(c => c.IntValue);

            // OK: TProperty == int. Prints "2"
            parent.Map(c => c.IEnumerableIntValue);

            // Wrong: TProperty == ICollection<int>. Prints "1"
            parent.Map(c => c.ICollectionIntValue);

            // Wrong: TProperty == List<int>. Prints "1"
            parent.Map(c => c.ListIntValue);

            // Wrong: TProperty == int[]. Prints "1"
            parent.Map(c => c.ArrayIntValue);
        }

        public class Class
        {
            public int IntValue { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<int> IEnumerableIntValue { get; set; }
            public ICollection<int> ICollectionIntValue { get; set; }
            public List<int> ListIntValue { get; set; }
            public int[] ArrayIntValue { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public class Parent<T>
    {
        public void Map<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            if (ReflectionHelpers.IsUnambiguousIEnumerableOfT(typeof(TProperty)))
            {
                MapMany(expression);
            }
            else
            {
                MapOne(expression);
            }
        }

        void MapOne(Expression expression)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
        }

        void MapMany(Expression expression)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }
    }

    static class ReflectionHelpers
    {
        public static bool IsUnambiguousIEnumerableOfT(Type type)
        {
            // Simple case - the type *is* IEnumerable<T>.
            if (IsIEnumerableOfT(type)) {
                return true;
            }

            // Harder - the type *implements* IEnumerable<T>.
            HashSet<Type> distinctIEnumerableImplementations = new HashSet<Type>();

            ExtractAllIEnumerableImplementations(type, distinctIEnumerableImplementations);

            switch (distinctIEnumerableImplementations.Count)
            {
                case 0: return false;
                case 1: return true;

                default:
                    // This may or may not be appropriate for your purposes.
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Multiple IEnumerable<> implementations detected.");
            }
        }

        private static bool IsIEnumerableOfT(Type type)
        {
            return type.IsGenericType
                && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>);
        }

        private static void ExtractAllIEnumerableImplementations(Type type, HashSet<Type> implementations)
        {
            foreach (Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                if (IsIEnumerableOfT(interfaceType)) {
                    implementations.Add(interfaceType);
                }

                ExtractAllIEnumerableImplementations(interfaceType, implementations);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem at all. Type inference simply fails and you have to explicitly specify the generic type parameters.

Comment: @InBetween, good point. That wasn't a strong argument at all, so I've chosen to remove it and focus on the scenario-specific workaround instead.